# How to programmatically change the primary color in Android L?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Is there a way to change programmatically the primary colors. I would like to do it in code depending on the screen/state of the app.

Currently I can only set the colors in the theme (static) :

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_color</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary_color</item>
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_color</item>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can, of course, implement custom subclasses of View that have methods for setting colors.

You can also define multiple themes with you various color schemes.

[Views](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) look up theme information from the context when they are created. So to change the styles applied from a theme you will have to recreate your view hierarchy with a context that uses the right theme.

One way to do that, is to create a new [ContextThemeWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) and then get a LayoutInflator that uses that theme wrapper, remove the old version of your layout and re-inflate your layout.

Roughly:

```java
ContextThemeWrapper themeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppThemeWithColorScheme2);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(themeWrapper);
viewContainer.removeAllViews();
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, viewContainer, true );
```

If you are using Action Bar, that may be a bit more tricky, because the Action Bar is created [once per activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java).

Comment: Thanks, recreating the activity is not an issue in my use case.So I ended writing all the theme in the style.xml, the only difference between them is the colors. I will see if I can improve with a ContextThemeWrapper.

Comment: Excellent explanation, my only question is: if my intention is to recreate the whole UI using a new theme, what is my 'viewContainer' ?

Answer (score 1):

USe this code for setting toolbarcolor and status bar (darker toolbar color)

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(toolbarColor);
factor=0.8f; 
int a = Color.alpha(toolbarcolor);
int r = Math.round(Color.red(toolbarcolor) * factor);
int g = Math.round(Color.green(toolbarcolor) * factor);
int b = Math.round(Color.blue(toolbarcolor) * factor);
int statusColor=Color.argb(a,
        Math.min(r, 255),
        Math.min(g, 255),
        Math.min(b, 255));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = MainActivity.this.getWindow();
    window.setStatusBarColor(statusColor);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. While this is indeed a programmatic way to change *some* colors, it is not a general way to change the app's primary color *everywhere*; that is, dynamically change the theme's color everywhere it is used.

Answer (score -1):

This is most practical with no error, there is no need to do any extra coding, just go to android tree project

> res > values  > colors  then edit these codes:

```
 <resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
</resources>
```

> add these under style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

> add into manifest just after ".MainActivity" :

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The question asks how to change these colors *programmatically*. That means, change them at run-time, in *code*.

Answer (score -1):

This change everything in text

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textGrey</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textGrey</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/textGrey</item>
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/textGrey</item>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The question asks how to change these colors *programmatically*. That means, change them at run-time, in *code*.