# How to _really_ programmatically change primary and accent color in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

First of all, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354558/how-to-change-programmatically-the-primary-color-in-android-l) asks a very similar question. However, my question has a subtle difference.

What I'd like to know is whether it is possible to programmatically change the `colorPrimary` attribute of a theme to an ***arbitrary*** color?

So for example, we have:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

At runtime, the user decides he wants to use `#ccffff` as a primary color. Ofcourse there's no way I can create themes for all possible colors.

I don't mind if I have to do hacky stuff, like relying on Android's private internals, as long as it works using the public SDK.

My goal is to eventually have the `ActionBar` *and* all widgets like a `CheckBox` to use this primary color.

Comment: You have no idea what "Android's private internals" are for a non-existent Android release. Do not assume that L's "private internals" are the same as those for whatever L turns into in terms of a production release.

Comment: No, you can't place arbitrary data into a theme. That said, colorPrimary is only used for the action bar background, recents bar color, and notifications color and you can change all of these dynamically.

Comment: I think you should ask "How to change style attribute in runtime", and from what I saw the answer is you cannot. However I have an idea that might help you. Use custom ContextWrapper and provide own Resources. Look at this: https://github.com/negusoft/holoaccent/blob/master/HoloAccent/src/com/negusoft/holoaccent/AccentResources.java In overall this project might give you an idea how to do that.

Comment: How about this suggestions? It's either having all desired Colors in Themes or overloading views with custom ones which allow to change their colors.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354558/how-to-change-programmatically-the-primary-color-in-android-l

Comment: @Jürgen'Kashban'Wahlmann Unfortunately, that's the way I do not want to do it - I want dynamic control over the colors, without having to manually create themes for all possible colors.

Comment: @NiekHaarman Then you have to create custom views from all views you want to have that colors on. Perhaps future Android Versions will allow to change the primary color on the fly. Wondering: There is this new Palette function to get primary colors from images. I understand they are used to change the theme's colors for a harmonized view when showing such images. Any clues on the Palette sample application, if one exists?

Comment: Just brainfarting here, but all XML gets converted into .dex files that are loaded into your android application as java objects right. Doesn't that mean we should be able to create and set entire themes from code as well as generate the theme from a factory yet to be written? Sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: The GreenMatter library can help you achieve the functionality you are looking for: https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter

Comment: @NiekHaarman did you ever figure out a way?

Comment: Hi, can i set colorPrimary from java code instead of setting through the xml file?

Comment: You can use Cyanea to dynamically set the primary and accent colors: https://github.com/jaredrummler/Cyanea

Comment: From [IQ.feature' answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48517223/2289835)  I make some changes and moved this [project on Github.](https://github.com/RumitPatel/DynamicThemeColor)

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Themes are immutable, you can't.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! Not the answer I was looking for, but I guess I'll have to live with it :)

Comment: Hi @Chris Banes, but how did the contact app change the status bar color and toolbar color according to the contact's theme color? If it is possible, I think what Niek Haarman's need is not too far since he only need to store the color code that the user want. Could you please explain more on this? I also want to create something like this but am really confused with it.

Comment: Status Bar color can be changed dynamically via Window.setStatusBarColor().

Comment: Is it possible to create a theme programmatically?

Comment: And while changing status bar color dynamically you can also change navigation bar color via Window.setNavigationBarColor() - API 21 :)

Comment: I don't think so. Check out Lifx app. Theme changes color according to the color wheel.

Comment: can't you bring these capabilities in Android M?

Comment: Themes are not _strictly_ immutable, see my answer.

Comment: @AndrewOrobator As of 2020 this does not appear so.

Answer (score 70):

I read the comments about contacts app and how it use a theme for each contact.

Probably, contacts app has some predefine themes (for each material primary color from here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html).

You can apply a theme before a the setContentView method inside onCreate method.

Then the contacts app can apply a theme randomly to each user.

This method is:

```
setTheme(R.style.MyRandomTheme);
```

But this method has a problem, for example it can change the toolbar color, the scroll effect color, the ripple color, etc, but it cant change the status bar color and the navigation bar color (if you want to change it too).

Then for solve this problem, you can use the method before and:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_red_500));
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_red_700));
    }
```

This two method change the navigation and status bar color.
Remember, if you set your navigation bar translucent, you can't change its color.

This should be the final code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.MyRandomTheme);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myrandomcolor1));
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myrandomcolor2));
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

You can use a switch and generate random number to use random themes, or, like in contacts app, each contact probably has a predefine number associated.

A sample of theme:

```
<style name="MyRandomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myrandomcolor1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myrandomcolor2</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/myrandomcolor1</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, my request was to use an **arbitrary** color. Of course it is not feasible to create themes for all colors.

Comment: @DanielGomezRico - AFAIK you can override the pre-set theme regardless of where initially set - as long as you do it early enough. As answer says *"You can apply a theme before the setContentView method inside onCreate method."*

Answer (score 61):

You can use [Theme.applyStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#applyStyle(int,%20boolean)) to modify your theme at runtime by applying another style to it.

Let's say you have these style definitions:

```
<style name="DefaultTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_lime_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_lime_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_amber_A400</item>
</style>

<style name="OverlayPrimaryColorRed">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_red_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_red_700</item>
</style>

<style name="OverlayPrimaryColorGreen">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_green_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_green_700</item>
</style>

<style name="OverlayPrimaryColorBlue">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_blue_700</item>
</style>
```

Now you can patch your theme at runtime like so:

```
getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.OverlayPrimaryColorGreen, true);
```

The method `applyStyle`has to be called before the layout gets inflated! So unless you load the view manually you should apply styles to the theme before calling `setContentView` in your activity.

Of course this cannot be used to specify an arbitrary color, i.e. one out of 16 million (256<sup>3</sup>) colors. But if you write a small program that generates the style definitions and the Java code for you then something like one out of 512 (8<sup>3</sup>) should be possible.

What makes this interesting is that you can use different style overlays for different aspects of your theme. Just add a few overlay definitions for `colorAccent` for example. Now you can combine different values for primary color and accent color *almost* arbitrarily.

You should make sure that your overlay theme definitions don't accidentally inherit a bunch of style definitions from a parent style definition. For example a style called `AppTheme.OverlayRed` implicitly inherits all styles defined in `AppTheme` and all these definitions will also be applied when you patch the master theme. So either avoid dots in the overlay theme names or use something like `Overlay.Red` and define `Overlay` as an empty style.

Comment: Try calling `applyStyle` before calling `setContentView` in your activity and it should work.

Comment: yea okai, then it might work ! i'm searching for a way to change the coloraccent in fragment niveau not activity ! thats why it didn't work for me sadly :< 

My use case is that I want different colors for FAB or tab indicators when switching from tabs which will start a different fragment !

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! However, I'm not able to do it multiple times. (one for colorPrimary, one for colorAccent, etc). Could you help me? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779821/gettheme-applystyle-multiple-times-without-overwriting-the-previous-one

Comment: That's the kind of answer for which I want to use a second account just to +1 once more. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was what i was looking for.... i hope i can change the Accent color of the current theme using this approach.

Answer (score 42):

I've created some solution to make any-color themes, maybe this can be useful for somebody. **API 9+**

**1.** first create "**res/values-v9/**" and put there this file: [styles.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YQTtkOUg95JgeAMUl-MKby1ScVsKV0LA)
and regular "res/values" folder will be used with your styles.

**2.** put this code in your res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#000</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeDarkActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#000</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**3.** in to AndroidManifest:

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppThemeDarkActionBar">
```

**4.** create a new class with name "ThemeColors.java"

```
public class ThemeColors {

    private static final String NAME = "ThemeColors", KEY = "color";

    @ColorInt
    public int color;

    public ThemeColors(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String stringColor = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY, "004bff");
        color = Color.parseColor("#" + stringColor);

        if (isLightActionBar()) context.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        context.setTheme(context.getResources().getIdentifier("T_" + stringColor, "style", context.getPackageName()));
    }

    public static void setNewThemeColor(Activity activity, int red, int green, int blue) {
        int colorStep = 15;
        red = Math.round(red / colorStep) * colorStep;
        green = Math.round(green / colorStep) * colorStep;
        blue = Math.round(blue / colorStep) * colorStep;

        String stringColor = Integer.toHexString(Color.rgb(red, green, blue)).substring(2);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = activity.getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(KEY, stringColor);
        editor.apply();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) activity.recreate();
        else {
            Intent i = activity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(activity.getPackageName());
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            activity.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    private boolean isLightActionBar() {// Checking if title text color will be black
        int rgb = (Color.red(color) + Color.green(color) + Color.blue(color)) / 3;
        return rgb > 210;
    }
}
```

**5.**  MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new ThemeColors(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view){
        int red= new Random().nextInt(255);
        int green= new Random().nextInt(255);
        int blue= new Random().nextInt(255);
        ThemeColors.setNewThemeColor(MainActivity.this, red, green, blue);
    }
}
```

To change color, just replace Random with your RGB, Hope this helps.

[image]

There is a complete example: [ColorTest.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-uPtFdEfNFpdeM6_3oUNtn62RRoQ_v8L/view?usp=sharing)

You can have a look at this [GitHub project](https://github.com/RumitPatel/Android-Dynamic-Theme-Color) from [Rumit Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2289835/rumit-patel).

Comment: can you share project like?

Comment: Create new project, download file - "styles.xml", and use code that above. Good luck.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around         `context.setTheme(context.getResources().getIdentifier("T_" + stringColor, "style", context.getPackageName()));` can you give me a explaination or a link to follow up on this topic?

Comment: Look in "styles.xml" file ... there are a list of available themes. context.setTheme(context.getResources().getIdentifier("T_" + stringColor, "style", context.getPackageName())); To get one of theme by name.

Comment: The activity recreate takes too long I think. I am using the refresh when navigating to a new fragment with bottom navigation bar, and the lag to re-create colors is noticeable.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X6uwpJ_2Lsm93qnyMLvzId1_koPsgeTb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @IQ.feature I think pushing your code to Github repo is more suitable for code sharing

Comment: Just to be clear for others because I fell for this... there is a file res-v9/styles.xml which declares a whole list of themes with different colors and the code essentially applies one of those themes and recreates the activity. It's what other answers have also tried to achieve.. i.e. it's a workaround by predefining themes it's not programmatically or dynamically creating themes.

Comment: You cann't do it...No way to create themes dynamically.

Comment: how do I get the color as an int from this class and set widget background ?

Comment: int color = R.color.colorPrimary , remain the same , why ?

Comment: Look in "buttonClick", it's example how to call function with a new Theme. RGB - take int values whatever you want.

Comment: I make some changes and moved this [project on Github.](https://github.com/RumitPatel/DynamicThemeColor)

Comment: OK, I will add your link in the post...

Answer (score 3):

I used the Dahnark's code but I also need to change the ToolBar background:

```
if (dark_ui) {
    this.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Dark);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Theme_Dark_primary));
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Theme_Dark_primary_dark));
    }
} else {
    this.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Light);
}

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

if(dark_ui) {
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Theme_Dark_primary));
}
```

Comment: add this code: android:background="?attr/colorPrimary", to your toolbar (in the .xml file), so you don't need to set the background in java.

Comment: But I have two different Toolbars, one for a light theme an another for a dark theme. If I add the  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" I have to use some kind of selector.

Comment: I had a lot themes and I only use that code. Take a look to this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.videumcorp.desarrolladorandroid.materialdesignnavigationdrawer

Answer (score 1):

from an activity you can do:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(i color);
```

Comment: Funny that this answer has -8 votes but solves my problem :D

Answer (score 1):

You can change define your own themes, or customize existing android themes in res > values > themes, find where it says primary color and point it to the color defined in color.xml you want

[image]

```
 <style name="Theme.HelloWorld" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/my_color</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the color of colorPrimary, but you can change the theme of your application by adding a new style with a different colorPrimary color

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NewTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorOne</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorOneDark</item>
</style>
```

and inside the activity set theme

```
 setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NewTheme);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: I see that there are already earlier answers that describe switching styles. Under what situation is your answer more appropriate than those? And to be clear, the question says *"At runtime, the user decides he wants to use #ccffff as a primary color. Of course there's no way I can create themes for all possible colors."* This doesn't solve that need; however if no one had described how to do this, it would be useful to know.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Did you get any solution

Comment: @sejn - you do something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905131/199364) - and *then* you must *remove* (pop from nav stack) whatever is showing on screen, and push a new instance of it again - to force "inflate" to happen again, creating a new view with revised theme. Exact details depend on whether you are using fragments, and can easily replace the current one, or instead must re-start the current activity. Google elsewhere for help with that step, or post a new question describing what you need to do - reference this Q&A, explain the step you have not solved.

Answer (score -2):

**USE A TOOLBAR**

You can set a custom **toolbar** item color dynamically by creating a custom toolbar class:

```
package view;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter;
import android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView;
import android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomToolbar extends Toolbar{

    public CustomToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        ctxt = context;
    }

    int itemColor;
    Context ctxt;

    @Override 
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        Log.d("LL", "onLayout");
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        colorizeToolbar(this, itemColor, (Activity) ctxt);
    } 

    public void setItemColor(int color){
        itemColor = color;
        colorizeToolbar(this, itemColor, (Activity) ctxt);
    }



    /**
     * Use this method to colorize toolbar icons to the desired target color
     * @param toolbarView toolbar view being colored
     * @param toolbarIconsColor the target color of toolbar icons
     * @param activity reference to activity needed to register observers
     */
    public static void colorizeToolbar(Toolbar toolbarView, int toolbarIconsColor, Activity activity) {
        final PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter
                = new PorterDuffColorFilter(toolbarIconsColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        for(int i = 0; i < toolbarView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View v = toolbarView.getChildAt(i);

            doColorizing(v, colorFilter, toolbarIconsColor);
        }

      //Step 3: Changing the color of title and subtitle.
        toolbarView.setTitleTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        toolbarView.setSubtitleTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
    }

    public static void doColorizing(View v, final ColorFilter colorFilter, int toolbarIconsColor){
        if(v instanceof ImageButton) {
            ((ImageButton)v).getDrawable().setAlpha(255);
            ((ImageButton)v).getDrawable().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        }

        if(v instanceof ImageView) {
            ((ImageView)v).getDrawable().setAlpha(255);
            ((ImageView)v).getDrawable().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        }

        if(v instanceof AutoCompleteTextView) {
            ((AutoCompleteTextView)v).setTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        }

        if(v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        }

        if(v instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText)v).setTextColor(toolbarIconsColor);
        }

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup){
            for (int lli =0; lli< ((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); lli ++){
                doColorizing(((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(lli), colorFilter, toolbarIconsColor);
            }
        }

        if(v instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            for(int j = 0; j < ((ActionMenuView)v).getChildCount(); j++) {

                //Step 2: Changing the color of any ActionMenuViews - icons that
                //are not back button, nor text, nor overflow menu icon.
                final View innerView = ((ActionMenuView)v).getChildAt(j);

                if(innerView instanceof ActionMenuItemView) {
                    int drawablesCount = ((ActionMenuItemView)innerView).getCompoundDrawables().length;
                    for(int k = 0; k < drawablesCount; k++) {
                        if(((ActionMenuItemView)innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[k] != null) {
                            final int finalK = k;

                            //Important to set the color filter in seperate thread, 
                            //by adding it to the message queue
                            //Won't work otherwise. 
                            //Works fine for my case but needs more testing

                            ((ActionMenuItemView) innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[finalK].setColorFilter(colorFilter);

//                              innerView.post(new Runnable() {
//                                  @Override
//                                  public void run() {
//                                      ((ActionMenuItemView) innerView).getCompoundDrawables()[finalK].setColorFilter(colorFilter);
//                                  }
//                              });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

then refer to it in your layout file. Now you can set a custom color using

```
toolbar.setItemColor(Color.Red);
```

**Sources:**

I found the information to do this here: [How to dynamicaly change Android Toolbar icons color](https://snowdog.co/blog/how-to-dynamicaly-change-android-toolbar-icons-color/)

and then I edited it, improved upon it, and posted it here: [GitHub:AndroidDynamicToolbarItemColor](https://github.com/powerpoint45/AndroidDynamicToolbarItemColor)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Especially the part "My goal is to eventually have the ActionBar _and all widgets like a CheckBox to use this primary color._".

Comment: Then just add on to include a checkbox. For example, add if (v instanceof CheckBox) {themeChexnoxWithColor(toolbarIconsColor) ; I don't see how this doesn't answer your question honestly

Comment: @nhaarman you can dynamically set the actionbar color like this stackoverflow.com/questions/23708637/change-actionbar-background-color-dynamically I just don't exactly understand your question

Comment: I have an app where the user can choose the actionbar color and actionbar item colors.  I don't see what else you need

Comment: Even if this only answers part of your question,  it is still a large and critical part

Answer (score -6):

This is what you CAN do:

write a file in drawable folder, lets name it background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

then set your Layout's (or what so ever the case is) `android:background="@drawable/background"`

on setting your theme this color would represent the same.