# Android: How to change theme attributes dynamically at runtime from code

Tags: android, dynamic, attributes, themes, runtime

I'm using AppCompat, my app has dynamic color themes. I want to be able to change the `primaryColor` and `accentColor` attributes so that UI elements will match the theme colors (e.g. progress bars, check boxes, etc.).

I can manually set colors for a lot of views, but that gets complicated for elements like checkboxes and progress bars where I do not want to generate my own drawable. Obviously using static XML doesn't work for this either.

Is changing theme attributes for an Activity possible from code?

Comment: Pallete class can be used.

Comment: @Simar I don't want to generate other colors, I already have the colors I want. I'm trying to change global theme colors of the Activity.

Comment: Yeah. That can be done by this class.

Comment: I have the same question. Looking forward to an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to \_really\_ programmatically change primary color in Android Lollipop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-color-in-android-lollipop)

Comment: @Simar no it can't: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

Comment: You simply can't. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll).

Comment: @RishabhBhardwaj I know. I made a library for it.