# Is it possible to modify a theme at runtime?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

I'd like to dynamically change attributes in this theme: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. In particular, I'd like to change the colorPrimary, colorAccent, and colorPrimaryDark attributes based on the data being displayed so that particular widgets like `EditText`s can be themed appropriately. I know that I'd have to change the theme before `setContentView(...)` of my Activity but how do I change particular attributes in the theme before I do that?

Edit: From @reVerse's comment linking to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll) I know that it's impossible to change a Theme as they are immutable. Is it possible to create a Theme programmatically?

Comment: [That's not possible (click for similiar SO-Question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll)

Comment: Is it possible to create a theme via code?

Comment: Unfortunately that's also not possible. Your only option is to color each view manually via your code.

Comment: If you can live with a fixed-size color palette you can create style overlay definitions and then use [Theme.applyStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#applyStyle(int,%20boolean)) to modify the theme at runtime, see my answer to that other SO question.