# How to prevent screen flickering on theme change?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-dark-theme

I am trying to implement dark theme in my app.
I am using Android [Preferences DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore?gclsrc=ds&gclsrc=ds&gclid=CKeEkYrQs_ICFUNHjgodB-MEEQ#preferences-datastore) to save user preference for theme.
The datastore class exposes a flow for preferred theme `themeFLow` and a suspend function `updateTheme()` to update the preferred theme.

I have a ThemeManager class to manage theme changes. It looks like this.

```kotlin
class ThemeManager {
    
    private val currentTheme = themeDataStore.themeFlow
    
    init {
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            currentTheme.collect {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(it)
            }
        }
    }

    fun setCurrentTheme(newTheme: Int) {
        scope.launch {
            themeDataStore.updateTheme(newTheme)
        }
    }
}
```

In UI, I display a dialog box to choose current theme and call `themeManager.setCurrentTheme(newTheme)`
The problem is that theme changes with a flicker. See [video](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/51705072/129532916-01e1c6c5-3436-48bc-89d3-fdf3e5029623.mp4) (slowed down)

Other SO answers on this question (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174042/how-to-switch-themes-night-mode-without-restarting-the-activity) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845646/transition-when-theme-switching-or-activity-recreate)) provide a solution which involves finishing and restarting the activity.
In my app, I am following a single activity + fragments architecture (using Jetpack Navigation Library), so when I restart activity like this, activity starts from home fragment and the current destination is lost.

Is there some way to get rid of this flickering?

Answer (score 0):

On click of some button / trigger, you can use below code in the fragment to recreate current activity:

```
val intent = activity?.intent
intent?.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_IS_THEME_CHANGED, true)
activity?.finish()
startActivity(intent)
activity?.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
```

I have tried this in my project and it works fine without flickering. You can even check for the boolean `EXTRA_KEY_IS_THEME_CHANGED` to navigate to the specific fragment with the help of navigation.

```
navController.navigate(R.id.fragment_you_need_to_show)
```

Comment: But the transition from startDestination to the desiredFragment will be visible if I navigate after activity recreation. Isn't it so?

Comment: Yeah probably. You may want to try `NavOptions` to define empty animations but note that it is not a recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue when i changed the whole app language, in my application i have one navigation host activity and rest are fragment like you.

```
override fun recreate() {
    finish()
    overridePendingTransition(
        R.anim.empty_animation,
        R.anim.empty_animation
    )
    startActivity(intent)
    overridePendingTransition(
        R.anim.empty_animation,
        R.anim.empty_animation
    )
}
```

Paste it in your base or navigation host activity, it works for me. I have given empty animation according to my requirements depend on you, you can give fade in or fade out animations for beauty.