# Theme from Palette

Tags: android, palette

I'm making an app that retrieve a lot of images from some server. I'm tinting each item in my List using Palette library. When a choose one I open another activity to show details of this item.

I want to build a theme based on the selected theme to apply in detail activity.

Is there a way to programmatically build a theme based on a Palette from a Bitmap?

Comment: Yes! But is it about the styles, color or background?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Unless you instantiate components manually. However, you can quickly set the colors by calling specific methods of the components. If  you are looking for a Palette that can be passed through activities, take a look at this https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/0c7ab7dba4f795891a26

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung I wanna build a new theme with primary, primaryDark and accentColor to apply in my activity

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski looks really cool but I still don't get how it could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is about the color of material design, there is a solution.

1. Remember: You cannot change the [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll?answertab=oldest#tab-top) those colors at runtime but you can switch between themes at activity start.
2. When an user select a color, apply corresponding style and restart activity. Otherwise, change some other colors like [Google keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep&hl=en)
3. To set theme .

   `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setTheme(...style.YourTheme);`
4. To restart activity: Call the [recreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) method of the activity.