# changing app material theme colorPrimaryDark programatically in android?

Tags: android, material-design

Can I change the  colorPrimaryDark color of material theme programmatically?

I want to apply different colorPrimaryDark color based on the navigation Item choosed, is there any alternative other than setting different styles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \_really\_ programmatically change primary and accent color in Android Lollipop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll)

Comment: this is not duplicate, I want to change primaryColorDark color so want to change statusbar color programatically, though there is a way to change status bar color, I want it transparent and make colorPrimaryDark as a statusbar color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way such as per current available methods of android sdk. So Instead of changing colorPrimaryDark attribute programatically, I am applying different themes for different activities