# Change android Material design colors at runtime

Tags: android, themes

I want to be able to change the colors of my android app at runtime (which is using the material design).

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll) I see that I can change the theme to any predefined style at runtime. Nice!

But what if I want to use *any* colors?

Maybe I can create a theme/style at runtime?

Comment: well by colors what do you mean background colors ??

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it is more clear now