# Dynamic colours in an app

Tags: android, colors, textview

I have colors  of text and button come dynamic form backend, 
I need to change this color of text dynamically when change happens in backend all at time.

I could make it manual

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_color));
```

Is there a way to change group of text color  dynamically  or must set every text color manually in code?

I searched for how to change theme colors  dynamically at run time and  i found this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26511725/7437508).

But I also search again and I found this [github](https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter)
but it doesn't work on Android Marshmallow (6.0+) and it's use is discouraged! as he say.

Is there any lib or method to change the theme on runtime?

Comment: You need to provide some information about what your issue is and how you have tried to resolve it, or what research you have done already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll
check this link ,please my problem like this case, but for group of text

Comment: Do you have any code to show the text and buttons you are trying to change? If so, please edit the question and put it in there. Also, is there anything in the link you provided in your comment that makes you think this should be different? If so, perhaps you could explain why you have looked at that question and you think there is a reason your question should get a different response. Overall, please put more detail into your question to help people understand what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it's impossible and not viable because of themes are immutable.

[GreenMatter](https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter) becomes outdated so regretfully the answer of your question is **No way**.

More precisely, the color overriding at runtime is not working. There is no fix found at the moment. The future of this feature is uncertain.

Comment: i know that @hassan Magdy that what i was talking about