# Changing TextInputLayout's Focus color dynamically programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-textinputlayout

I'm working on an android app using kotlin.

I'm asked to implement a feature where the user picks a color upon signup, and this color is later the main color for this user in the app. Where the action bar, buttons, and textinputlayouts should change color.

[Before the user picks a color (app default theme color)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqWfG.jpg)

[This is where I reached after the user picks the color from the color picker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJc09.jpg)

Any idea how to change the color of the textinputlayouts accordingly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change the Color Accent in the App Theme

```
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
```

Comment: Is it possible to change it programmatically? If yes please provide how.

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll

Comment: Thank you so much! It took a lot of work but finally worked. With a small trade off though.

Comment: Welcome, Keep Coding