# How to apply themes with custom primary color (change theme color) at runtime

Tags: android, reflection, android-theme

Say I have a theme color selector for the user to choose custom colors (hex color integer, for example) as theme color for the app, how should I do it?

This is pretty much the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25815769/8170714), but since it's never got a proper answer and it's four years ago, I wonder if there's a way that we could do it now. Reflection methods, for example, might be able to some tricks to make it work, but I have no idea where to start with them.

Update: I already explained that my question is basically asking for the same thing as the duplicated question did, but since no one came up with any feasible solutions under that question, I decided to bring up this question again 4 years later to see if someone has come up some solution to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \_really\_ programmatically change primary and accent color in Android Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll)

Comment: @Darish I already explained that my question is asking for the same thing the duplicated question did, but since no one came up with any feasible solutions under that question, I decided to bring up this question again 4 years later to see if someone has come up some solution to it.

Comment: Taking your question literally (you want to change the *style* at runtime) I am not aware of any way to do it. If you want to change the *colors used by widgets* at runtime, there should be options for that, perhaps with a custom `ContextWrapper`. Take a peek at https://github.com/garretyoder/Colorful and see how it is handling the problem.

Comment: "since it's never got a proper answer" -- note that the question has many answers, a few of which have many upvotes. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain in detail your situation, to clearly distinguish what you are trying to do from what is offered by the answers on that question.

Comment: @CommonsWare got it, will take a look at ContextWrapper.