# Changing Android's EditText cursor pointer color programmatically

Tags: android, pointers, colors, android-edittext

So, i've searched a lot but i couldn't find anything, if this ends up being a duplicate i'm sorry, but i want to cange the color of the EditText's cursor pointer that is used to move the cursor

[image]

I already managed to change the cursor's color itself but it doesn't affect the pointer which seems to only respond to accentColor.

I'm pretty sure it's possible because i recall seeing an app that did it, it had the pointer and all the elements in a dialog change color based on a color that you choose without changing the accent color of the view below the dialog.

Please help :)

Comment: As you said, I think you can change this color by changing accentColor

Comment: Yes but changing accent color would change also the color of the underlying elements that are hardwired to accent color

Comment: Maybe you can create a custom theme for this edit text and set the accentColor as desired

Comment: i didn't think about that, i'll try in a moment and let you know, do you know of a way to change a theme's accent color programmatically?

Comment: Can check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354558/how-to-change-programmatically-the-primary-color-in-android-l  but doesn't seems as easy as only add few lines in the styles.xml :)

Comment: i finally tried to do it and the theme works but it's too complicated to change programmatically so it's not worth it

Answer (score 7):

You can create your own style/theme for only this EditText and change the ColorAccent :

```
<style name="EditTextColorCustom" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by creating new style in style.xml like this

```
<style name="CustomEditTextTheme" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>       
</style>
```

Then in EditText tag use this

```
style="@style/CustomEditTextTheme"
```

Comment: Instead of style=... I wrote `android:theme="@style/CustomEditTextTheme"`.

Comment: `<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>      `
use this instead if `colorAccent` is not working

Answer (score 2):

you can use textSelectHandle to replace it by your drawable like this:

```
android:textSelectHandle="@drawable/your_drawble"
```

Comment: none of suggested variants worked for my TextInputEditText or AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView, and only this one. I used "invert_colors" vector from Android Studio icons

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to set selectHandle.

EditText has Editor class that has the mSelectHandleCenter field (if you need selection use mSelectHandleLeft and mSelectHandleRight)

```
private fun setCursorPointerColor(view: EditText, @ColorInt color: Int) {
    try {
        //get the pointer resource id
        var field = TextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mTextSelectHandleRes")
        field.isAccessible = true
        val drawableResId = field.getInt(view)

        //get the editor
        field = TextView::class.java.getDeclaredField("mEditor")
        field.isAccessible = true
        val editor = field.get(view)

        //tint drawable
        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.context, drawableResId)!!
        drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)

        //set the drawable
        field = editor.javaClass.getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleCenter")
        field.isAccessible = true
        field.set(editor, drawable)

    } catch (ex: Exception) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add colorControlActivated to your AppTheme in style :

`<item name="colorControlActivated">"Your_color"</item>`

Comment: well this actually works.. but i think it will override color accent setting